# How display a pdf document into a Webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, webclient

I want to show a PDF in a new activity on android, I'm working with webview's and I have a pure PHP webpage that when I enter a code in an INPUT and press the button opens a new page with the PDF file created and according to the code entered

[INPUT + BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTT5f.png)

[NEW PDF PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBsUv.png)

I have these permissions on android

```
webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    htmlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    htmlWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    htmlWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    htmlWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
    htmlWebView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
```

I know that Android can not show PDF in the same webview)

I did the following, press the button on the web and start downloading the PDF already created without opening the page with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
 echo fread($fp, 65536);
 } 
fclose($fp);
```

but it still does not work and I use the following code to download other files without opening them, direct download..

```
 htmlWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading PDF...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,".pdf");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading PDF...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```

There is some other technique that I do not know because I have researched days and I can not find anything ..

Comment: `WebView` has no built-in ability to display a PDF. You will need to look into [various PDF rendering options](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Docs Viewer to read your pdf online:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```